# Match DSM tiled data

Tags: qgis, lidar, lastools, laz

I have an 282 `.laz`  tiles for a large area. The aim was to extract the DSM and DTM data in `.asc`  format to hopefully get building heights from them. I used lastools to convert them the DSM `.laz`  data to `.asc`  files. This worked great, but now when I view this `.asc` data in QGIS, it looks like the height information isnt calibrated to the same datum (apologies for not using the right terminology) Is there a way to ensure that all the tiles have uniform height reference?
[image]